# Photoshop CC 2015 Save Action is not overwriting the original PNG file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2015

I just updated to Photoshop CC 2015 for OSX.

When I had Photoshop CC 2014, I had an action:

```
 - Change hue
 - Change levels
 - Save
 - Close
```

Which I could batch on hundreds of PNG images. The `Save` command would simply overwrite the PNG files.

But this seems to be broken in Photoshop CC 2015. When I run the action on batch, after processing one of my images, `Save` will open a Save Dialog! I don't want that. I want it to simply overwrite the source image.

I tried changing the `Save` command in the action to `Save As` and select `.PNG` as the format. The dialog is gone, but now all the processed files are saved to the exact same image (the one that is set in the action)... so it is useless.

Then I tried the Image Processor script in Photoshop, but the damn thing does not output with the `.PNG` format.

How can I make my action work? I just want `Save` to overwrite the source file. No dialogs. I don't have Bridge or any other Adobe software - I feel it is too much for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it working with a bit of scripting, which is kind of disappointing. The action is this now:

```
 - Change hue
 - Change levels
 - Call script
```

And the script is this:

```
app.activeDocument.saveAs(new File(app.activeDocument.fullName), new PNGSaveOptions());
app.activeDocument.close();
```

So you run this action on a batch of images and they should all be overwritten as .PNG files.